# How can I make my Discord Bot send a message every-time a user types 'verify'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have tried to search the web for ways to do this, but I've had no luck. I know this is seems very easy, but I am just starting with discord.py and I'm looking for some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your bot code.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
   if message.content == ‘verify’:
      await message.channel.send(“A message”)
```

Comment: Thanks, but where would I put my bots token?

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: from the context of your question I thought that you already have a functional bot program, so I provided that snippet which you can add

Answer (score -1):

Here

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "verify":
        #Your code
```

Comment: Thanks, but where would I put my bots token?

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

```py
import discord

token = '<insert-token-here>'

# Make sure to enable the Message Content intent in the Discord developer portal
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged on as {client.user}")

@client.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        # skip message from self
        return
    print(f"Message: {message.content}")
    await message.channel.send(message.content)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.run(token)
```